# Jquery insert inside a div tag

Tags: jquery

I have a Json response.I have to insert

inside

```
    <div id="xyz1">
    <ul>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="xyz2">
    <ul>

    </ul>
    </div>
for(var i=0; i<test.length; i++)
{
$("#xyz" + i).html('<li>' + test[i]  +'<li>'):

}
```

If I use above code it, is inserting only one

but If i Print my test.length, it is giving correct value as 2.

Comment: you have to use append or appendTo not html of jquery .. check jquery api api.jquery.com/append  so its $("#xyz" + i).append('<li>' + test[i]  +'<li>'):

Comment: @vishalsharma:even append or appendto is not working.

Comment: what's your json text means varaible test??

Comment: and by the way what's your parent element where you put this divs

Comment: @vishalsharma:my parent is div, ul is child. I was using $("xyx" + i > ul").html();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should push your `<li>` inside `ul`and not inside `<div>`

try this

```
$("#xyz" + i + " ul").html('<li>' + test[i]  +'<li>');
    //-----------^^---here addd this
```

**updated**(seeing comment)

```
$("#xyx" + i + "qwerty ul").html('<li>' + test[i]  +'<li>');
```

Comment: :my div id is some thing like this xyx1qwerty.

Comment: @user2218132 check my update.. if that is what you meant...:)

Comment: :Still only one li is getting inserted in first div second div there is no li.

Answer (score 1):

hey boy the array's first index is 0 but your div's first index is 1;
try it like this;

```
  <div id="xyz0">
    <ul>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="xyz1">
    <ul>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction, you're missing the `#`, and you're missing the `/` in `</li>`

```
for(var i=0; i<test.length; i++)
{
    $("#xyz" + i).html('<li>' + test[i]  +'</li>');
}
```

Comment: @user2218132 you still haven't give us the content of variable `test`